# Abrir formulario para editar con vue.js

Tags: vue.js

He buscado como realizar CRUD con Vue.js pero me encontre solo con la creacion y listado de registros y necesito poderlos editar y eliminarlos preferentemente con Vue.js Espero explicarme claramente lo que ya he realizado y a donde quiero llegar. Tengo un formulario para crear contactos con vue.js y me gustaría usar ese mismo formulario para poder editar utilizando vue.js

Este es el componente con el que veo la lista de contactos que ya tengo registrados, ahí mismo se encuentra el botón con el que me gustaría abrir el formulario para edición.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Sucursal</th>
                                <th>Colonia</th>
                                <th>Mapa</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <spinner v-show="loading"></spinner>
                            <tr v-for="office in offices" :key="office.id">
                                <td>{{ office.tradeName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ office.colony }}</td>
                                <td><a v-bind:href="office.googleMaps">Ver Ubicación</a></td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Esta es la parte del script con el que muestro los contactos

```
<script>
    import EventBus from '../../event-bus';

    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                offices:[],
                loading: true
            }
        },
        created(){
            EventBus.$on('office-added', data => {
                this.offices.push(data)
            })
        },
        mounted() {
            let currentRoute = window.location.pathname
            axios
                .get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000${currentRoute}/offices`)
                .then((res) => {
                    this.offices = res.data,
                    this.loading = false
                })
        },
    }
</script>
```

El formulario de creación lo tengo como componente de vue.js y esta de la siguiente manera:

```
<template>
    <div class="modal fade" id="addOffice" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar Sucursal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form @submit.prevent="saveOffice">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="tradeName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Nombre Sucursal</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="tradeName" v-model="tradeName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Calle</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="address" v-model="address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="extNumber" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Num. Exterior</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="extNumber" v-model="extNumber">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="intNumber" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Num. Interior</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="intNumber" v-model="intNumber">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="colony" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Colonia</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="colony" v-model="colony">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipCode" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Codigo Postal</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="zipCode" v-model="zipCode">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="municipality" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Municipio</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="municipality" v-model="municipality">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="state" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Estado</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="state" v-model="state">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Pais</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="country" v-model="country">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="googleMaps" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label form-control-sm text-right">Google Maps</label>
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="googleMaps" v-model="googleMaps">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import EventBus from '../../event-bus';

    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                tradeName: null,
                address: null,
                extNumber: null,
                intNumber: null,
                colony: null,
                zipCode: null,
                municipality: null,
                state: null,
                country: null,
                googleMaps: null
            }
        },
        methods: {
            saveOffice: function(){
                let currentRoute = window.location.pathname
                //console.log(currentRoute)
                axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000${currentRoute}/offices`,{
                    tradeName: this.tradeName,
                    address: this.address,
                    extNumber: this.extNumber,
                    intNumber: this.intNumber,
                    colony: this.colony,
                    zipCode: this.zipCode,
                    municipality: this.municipality,
                    state: this.state,
                    country:this.country,
                    googleMaps: this.googleMaps
                })
                .then(function(res){
                    $('#addOffice').modal('hide')
                    EventBus.$emit('office-added', res.data.office)
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err)
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

No tengo idea de como hacer el enlace en un boton o en un link para poder abrir el formulario. La idea seria usar el mismo que la creacion pero si se necesita hacer otro no hay problema. Espero me puedan apoyar con este problema.

Comment: las rutas estan de esta manera Route::get('customers/{customer}/contacts','ContactController@index');
Route::post('customers/{customer}/contacts','ContactController@store');

Comment: Usas un router?

Comment: como que un router?

Comment: Claro.. tu aplicacion como sabe que componente mostrar?

Comment: dentro de una vista tengo un componente que es un boton y en app.js los tengo registrados

Comment: Y como le dices que componente mostrar en tu vista? creo que agarraste un par de tutoriales malos. Editar registros no es muy diferente a lo que harias en cualquier lado. Lo que si, el manual explica claramente como usar los componentes. Para tu caso, te recomendaria que veas como funciona [Router para vue](https://router.vuejs.org/) y tambien para evitar usar un event bus (que quedo medio viejo) te recomendaria un store como [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) Creo que con eso vas a entender mejor como pasar datos de un lado a otro.

Comment: ok los reviso antes de continuar, gracias